# Objective-C Notify When a New Record has been Added to the Database(sqlite) and Update the TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm parsing a data that I received from a remote notification and then immediately save it on my database within the `AppDelegate`. But when I received a new remote notification while the app is running, the `UITableView` doesn't get updated with the new data.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) on how to use sqlite. But when it comes on notifying when a new element has been added to the database it doesn't work on me since my case is `AppDelegate` and `UITableViewController` and the tutorial's case is `ViewController` and `UITableViewController`

This is how the tutorial does it after implementing the protocol

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    EditInfoViewController *editInfoViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    editInfoViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

In my case it will be

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [segue destinationViewController];
    appDelegate.delegate = self;
}
```

and I will get this error:

> Cannot initialize a variable of type 'AppDelegate* __strong' with an
>   rvalue of type' __kindofUIViewCOntroller*'

What alternate can I use for prepareForSegue?

I'm kind of lost here so I will appreciate any help that I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this error is obvious because AppDelegate is not a UIViewController.
You are trying to push an AppDelegate object that's why you got an error.

In your case if you want to save data of newly received notification in AppDelegate then simply create a method in AppDelegate itself.

Then when you receive a notification simply call that method which will save your data to the database.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

 if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

     NSLog(@"Push received in Active State: %@", userInfo);
 }
 else {
     NSLog(@"Push received in InActive State: %@", userInfo);
 }

[self saveDataToDatabse:userInfo]; 
} 


#pragma mark - Private methods
-(void)saveDataToDatabse:(id)data {

 // your logic here

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NewDataSaved" object:nil];  
}
```

In your ViewController.m add observer in viewDidLoad Method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable:) name:@"NewDataSaved" object:nil];
} 

-(void)reloadTable:(NSNotification)notification {

   // your logic here  
  [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I did in my AppDelegate. I successfully saved the data to database but it is not being displayed in the tableView. I have to relaunch the app then the tableView will be updated with the new data.

Comment: To Update your tableView you need to take a new approach.
After your data is saved, You can post a notification and put observer in your ViewController. In that you can reload your table.
Other one you can do by Declaring new delegate in your AppDelegate and implement respected method in your Controller.
Then once your data is saved you can call that method of viewController using delegate.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can digest all that because I'm still not very good at iOS programming. But what I did so far was created a protocol in AppDelegate, add declaration for the delegate property, had method modified so the delegate method is called. My remaining problem is to make the TableViewController class the delegate of the AppDelegate one. How can I do that?

Comment: Please try with approach mentioned in answer.

Comment: Thanks brother! Now I just need to understand how your code works. You saved me a lot of time, really.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101835/discussion-between-iosenthusiatic-and-user3423040).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast a ViewController as an AppDelegate class here:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [segue destinationViewController];
```

You should be looking at that the destinationViewController is and use the correct class type. If you don't know try logging the destinationViewController out:

```
NSLog("viewController: %@", [segue destinationViewController]);
```

That's the first issue, not sure if there'll be any more.